# How to declare an object<template> in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linked-list

I'm having the hardest time figuring this thing out. The error is in line 58 of main.cpp, I wrote a noticeable comment on line 58.

```
|58|error: expected primary-expression before ';' token
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "LinkedList.h"
using namespace std;

bool eic(const string &str1, const string &str2){
    if(str1.length() != str2. length())
       return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++)
        if(toupper(str1[i]) != toupper(str2[i])) return false;
    return true;
}

vector<string> tokenizer(const string &str, char delim, bool emptyok)
{
    vector<string> tokens;
    string t;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == delim)
        {
            if(emptyok || (t.length() != 0))
                tokens.push_back(t);

            t.clear();
            continue;
        }

        t.push_back(str[i]);
    }
    if(emptyok || (t.length() != 0)) tokens.push_back(t);
    return tokens;
}

int main(){
    LinkedList<int> sList;// = LinkedList<int>;
    string input;
    cout << "Type 'commands' to see the list of commands" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    vector<string> inputV = tokenizer(input,' ',false);
    while(!eic(input,"exit")){
        if(eic(input,"commands")){
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Do not include <> in any commands" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Create <name of list>: Create a new list and names it." << endl;
            cout << "Print <name of list>: Prints out the entire list." << endl;
            cout << "Add <name of list> <item>: Adds an element to the list." << endl;
            cout << "Delete <name of list> <item>: Deletes an element from the list." << endl;
            cout << "DeleteAll <name of list> <item>: Deletes all occurences of the element from the list." << endl;
            cout << "MakeEmpty <name of list>: Removes all elements from the list." << endl;
            cout << "Length <name of list>: Tells you how many elements are in the list" << endl;
            cout << "Remove <name of list> deletes an entire list" << endl;
            cout << "Exit: Terminates the program" << endl;
        }
        else if(eic(inputV[0],"create")){
            sList = LinkedList<int>; // LINE 58 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            sList.setName(inputV[1]);
            cout << sList.getName();
            //cout << "This function is still under construction" << endl;
        }
        else if(eic(inputV[0],"print")){
            cout << "This function is still under construction" << endl;
        }
        else if(eic(inputV[0],"add")){
            //sList->insertItem(9);
            cout << "This function is still under construction" << endl;
        }
        else if(eic(inputV[0],"delete")){
            cout << "This function is still under construction" << endl;
        }
        else if(eic(inputV[0],"deleteAll")){
            cout << "This function is still under construction" << endl;
        }
        else if(eic(inputV[0],"makeEmpty")){
            cout << "This function is still under construction" << endl;
        }
        else if(eic(inputV[0],"length")){
            cout << "This function is still under construction" << endl;
        }
        else if(eic(inputV[0],"remove")){
            cout << "This function is still under construction" << endl;
        }
        else cout << endl << "Invalid inquiry, please enter 'commands' to see a list of valid commands." << endl;
        cin >> input;
    }
}
```

If you need it here is my LinkedList.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

template <class xtype>
LinkedList<xtype>::LinkedList()
{
    cout << "List created successfuly\n";
}

template <class xtype>
void LinkedList<xtype>::setLength(int x){
    length = x;
}

template <class xtype>
int LinkedList<xtype>::getLength(){
    return length;
}

template <class xtype>
void LinkedList<xtype>::setName(string x){
    name = x;
}

template <class xtype>
string LinkedList<xtype>::getName(){
    return name;
}

template <class xtype>
void LinkedList<xtype>::insertItem(xtype item){
    node<xtype> *temp = new node<xtype>;
    if(head == NULL || head->info > item){
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    else{
        node<xtype> *q = head;
        node<xtype> *p = head->next;

        while(p != head && p->info <= item){
            q = p;
            p = p->next;
        }
        q->next = temp;
        temp->next = p;
    }
}

template class LinkedList<int>;
```

And the LinkedList header file

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class xtype>
struct node{
    xtype info;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
};

template <class xtype>
class LinkedList
{
    public:
        LinkedList();
        int getLength();
        void setLength(int);
        void setName(string);
        string getName();
        //bool searchItem(xtype item);
        void insertItem(xtype item);
        //void deleteItem(xtype item);
        //int numOccur(xtype item);
    protected:
    private:
        node<xtype> *head;
        node<xtype> *term;
        int length;
        string name;
};

#endif // LINKEDLIST_H
```

Any help you can give me would be much appreciated. I'm brand new to c++, coming from java, and I've just been slaving over this all of last night up until now.

Comment: `LinkedList<int>` is the name of a type, not an object, to create a temporary object of that type do `LinkedList<int>()`. What you wrote is equivalent to `i = int;`

Comment: I'm about to stab something.... I can't believe that's what I was missing...... I need sleep

Comment: Yeah but then I get the feeling that he is intending to use it as `new LinkedList<int>()` because he has already created the "object" up where he declared it. @Anton Yershov are you new to C++?

Comment: No, you don't need to do either of those things.

Comment: Yea I'm new. Coming from Java

Comment: `LinkedList<int> sList;` is already creating the object. The `sList = LinkedList<int>();` creates a temporary object and then assigns it to `sList` nucking the previous object that was created... So it will work but it won't be doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: I was actually planning to make sList into an array in the future though, I want to be able to work with mutiple LinkedLists

Comment: I recommend reading http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: @AntonYershov - Don't add `[answered]`, `[solved]` or `[fixed]` words in the title.

Answer (score 4):

When you declare `sList` as `LinkedList<int>`, you already have invoked the default constructor to initialize `sList`.  There's no need to assign this explicitly, as you (try to) do in the failing line.

This demonstrates a confusing but vital concept when coming from Java to C++ : [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Comment: It's a valid way to clear a list though, i.e. re-initialize it to the default-constructed state

Comment: Erm, yes, `sList = LinkedList<int>();` will clear the object, assuming a sane assignment operator